# How can I show an error message in an ASP.NET project using a popup window?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm  using  this code but a compilation error occured. It says that `the name server does not exist in current context.` If I use `Microsoft.SqlServer.Server` then `.HtmlEncode does not exist in the context.`

How can I overcome this problem?

```
try { executing some code here which getting error 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('" +Server.HtmlEncode(ex.Message) + "')</script>");
}
```

Comment: Don't use `Server.HtmlEncode()`. Use `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode()` Regardless, you should use some other approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've personally found it better to simply pass the error up to the UI level and handle presenting the error in an Ajax calls error statement (assuming this is an exception you can't handle conditionally)

I also discourage just trickling the error's text up. Sometimes this can reveal the inner workings of your application more than you'd like people to know.

Try using ***`System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(string)`*** instead of `Server.HtmlEncode`

Comment: Thanks and holy crap that was a fast edit, literally seconds after I posted

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I'm beginner. This problem ruined my day. Thanks to  you for saving me... :)

Comment: Keep at it. We were all beginners once. Plus even after 10 years the big problems aren't the ones that get you, it's the little ones.